# How to highlight overflowed strings in vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, textarea, vuetify.js

I am using v-text-area component in vuetify, and trying to highlight overflowed strings.

```
<v-textarea
  v-model="messageContent"
  auto-grow
  rounded
  counter="250"
></v-textarea>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Overflowed string in the sense what do you mean? can you please expalin in details or create a codepen , that would really help to solve your issue faster

Comment: User inputs some strings, but it has limit. When the string overflow the limit, then the overflowed strings should be highlighted. Thank you.